# Who is StackElectronix and why does he tweet random questions?

Tags: support

Looking at the [edit history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/322847/revisions) for [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322847/how-to-decide-pcb-specification) I noticed this:

> Tweeted twitter.com/StackElectronix/status/894887081784344577

I have seen it on other questions. What is the significance of this? I assume it's a bot, but why does it happen? (And what's with the name?)

Comment: Doesn't have a very definitive answer but there's a bit about it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work. They're delayed a bit so crap likely to get closed / deleted doesn't get tweeted but no idea where the name came from.

Comment: Should probably have a mod bump this up to SE.meta

Comment: I believe tweeted posts are the one that reach the "hot" list.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is its a bot that has somehow hooked into old functionality of the site that was never turned off.

There [used to be a "tweet this" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/tweet-this-button)